# Code works on when I input value as 50 and not when I provide value for suncondition

Tags: java, if-statement

Used scanner for user input struggling to get in to if loop when providing value for suncondition

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner temp = new Scanner(System.in);
int temperature;
System.out.print("Enter the temperature : ");
temperature=temp.nextInt();
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner suncon= new Scanner(System.in);
String suncondition;
System.out.print("Enter the Sun condition : ");
suncondition=suncon.nextLine();

if ((temperature==50) || (suncondition=="Sunny")){
    System.out.println(" This is tooo hot");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**==** will compare if they refer to the same object in memory which is not the case here so it will be false.

Here you can use the equals method, this compares based on the data / content of the string.

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner temp = new Scanner(System.in);
int temperature;
System.out.print("Enter the temperature : ");
temperature=temp.nextInt();
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner suncon= new Scanner(System.in);
String suncondition;
System.out.print("Enter the Sun condition : ");
suncondition=suncon.nextLine();

if ((temperature==50) || (suncondition.equals("Sunny"))){
    System.out.println(" This is tooo hot");
}
```

If you would like to learn more about this here is a nice article

- [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-equals-compareto-equalsignorecase-and-compare/#:~:text=In%20Java%2C%20string%20equals(),matched%20then%20it%20returns%20false](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-equals-compareto-equalsignorecase-and-compare/#:%7E:text=In%20Java%2C%20string%20equals(),matched%20then%20it%20returns%20false).

Comment: Thanks This worked

Comment: You are welcome, if this was helpful for you can click the check button to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals()` to compare Strings. Only use `==` to compare primitives - comparing classes is usually comparing references.

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner temp = new Scanner(System.in);
int temperature;
System.out.print("Enter the temperature : ");
temperature=temp.nextInt();
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
String suncondition;
System.out.print("Enter the Sun condition : ");
suncondition=temp.nextLine();

if ((temperature==50) || (suncondition.equals("Sunny"))){
    System.out.println(" This is tooo hot");
}
```

Also, there is no need to create two Scanner objects when one could do.

Comment: Thanks for this, however without the second scanner object I am not able to enter the suncondition

Comment: @ChaitanyaDeshkar see: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Comment: Worked  when I changed it to suncondition=temp.next();